# Citation Style for the College Mathematics Journal?

Tags: publishing

I can't seem to find any information on what sort of citation style the College Mathematics Journal wants. Also, they say:

> Use the AMS standard abbreviations for journals, available here. Do not submit a >separate BibTeX file, instead incorporate the references into the same LaTeX file >as the article.
>
> - See more at: http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/information-authors-0#sthash.wp2xkOOr.dpuf

Does this mean that I am unable to use the bibtex package, or that I simply need to include the bibtex with the main script (using filecontents for example)

Comment: Why don't you just ask them by sending an email to cmj@maa.org (the email they give on their page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use Bibtex with the style you want.

Bibtex creates a .bbl file, which is written with the same syntax thebibliography uses and it contains the cited items only (the original bibtex database can be much bigger).

You can just paste the content of the bbl file at the end of your document.

David